# Is it possible to pass arguments into a Python script?

Tags: python

I know how to pass arguments into a shell script. These arguments are declared in AWS datapipeline and passed through. This is what a shell script would look like:

```
firstarg=$1
secondarg=$2
```

How do I do this in Python? Is it the exact same?

Comment: Have you tried to search before you asked? Searching google for *passing arguments to python script* brings all information you need. As the 4th link I got the question [Command Line Arguments In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1009860/95735) from Stackoverflow.

Comment: Searching google for passing arguments to python script brings _this_ post.

Comment: So recursion works

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import sys
firstarg=sys.argv[1]
secondarg=sys.argv[2]
thirdarg=sys.argv[3]
```

Comment: Yep, that works. For some reason, indexing does not start at 0. So `sys.argv[0]` is equal to nothing

Comment: `argv[0]` should be the script name

Answer (score 5):

You can use the argv from sys

```
from sys import argv
arg1, arg2, arg3, ... = argv
```

You can actually put an abitrary number of arguments in the command line.
argv will be a list with the arguments.
Thus it can also be called as
arg1 = sys.argv[0]
arg2 = sys.argv[1]
.
.
.

Keep also in mind that sys.argv[0] is simply the name of your python program.
Additionally, the "eval" and "exec" functions are nice when you use command line input. Usually, everything in the command line is interpreted as a string. So, if you want to give a formula in the command line you use eval().

```
>>> x = 1
>>> print eval('x+1')
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
# Display File name 
print("Script name ", sys.argv[0])
# Display the first argument
print(f"first arg {sys.argv[1]}")
```

Comment: You should enter this in sample.py and call with parameter.

Comment: ArunSK, you can edit your answer to include your comment. :)